# Keeping track of the latest releases

Tags: package-management, upgrade, distributions, rolling-release

How do people keep a track of the latest softwares being released? Let me say a distro group like slackware. A distro has ~25K+ packages and about a score of people involved. I hardly think these people keep checking the site of individual developers to see if they have released anything.

Is there a an automatic way? A script? A standardized RSS feed? or a mailing list (parsable mails)?

Comment: Your question is about people keeping track, but your proposed answers seem more like things machines would consume. Do you have a particular use case you're trying to solve, like automatically stay on the latest-and-greatest for some subset of packages?

Comment: Yes. I would like to stay on the latest & greatest. (latest stable or beta as the user may choose). I am trying to seek if there is a solution already than proposing one. The machine readability is to assist the human decision maker.

Comment: If 'latest and greatest' is your goal, be prepared to do a lot of system debugging and you'll have a lot of build and installation headaches.

Comment: I understand that. I was trying to put together the things that it would take to build and maintain a distro. This is all hypothetical . Just for academic interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Debian: Most Debian package sources include a [`debian/watch`](http://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch) file. There is a [service](http://wiki.debian.org/DEHS) (currently not working) which scans these files regularly and informs the corresponding package maintainers if there are new upstream versions.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most software pops up in my Software Center on my desktop. Most Linuxes have such a tool running by default. For HP-UX, Solaris and AIX I usually get en email from supplier or patch at given intervals.

- For third party software I subscribe to its RSS feed in an [RSS aggregator](http://rnews.sourceforge.net/news.php).
- For third party software without RSS feed I use [WebMonX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webmonx/), which is a little desktop program that pops up a notification when a webpage has changed.
- Don't forget to subscribe to third party security vulnerability feeds too. These feeds may flag software updates in an early stage.