# Tool to watch latest software releases from upstream?

Tags: debian, software-rec

Does anyone know of a program/framework to watch latest software releases from upstream? For example for wordpress, apache/nginx, and so on. The program should just retrieve respective software project's webpage (or FTP listing, whatever) and parse it to grab the version numbers and tarball URLs.

Imagined invocation and output of such program:

```
% swwatch wordpress
branch: 3.4
status: release
version: 3.4.2
date: ...
tarball url: http://...

branch: 3.5
status: beta
version: 3.5.0-beta2
date: ...
tarball url: http://...
```

There is a related question: [Keeping track of the latest releases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36932/keeping-track-of-the-latest-releases) , and I'm checking out debian/watch right now, but this requires downloading the package source. And it also means I have to wait until a Debian maintainer uploads a new version, which can be a while. I'd prefer something more lightweight that checks the upstream information directly.

Comment: Arch has https://github.com/keenerd/pkgbuild-watch It is Arch-centric, but may provide some inspiration if you wanted to roll your own...

Comment: @jasonwryan: If I glanced the script correctly, it watches for new Arch package version instead of new upstream version?

Comment: No: it is *for* PKGBUILD maintainers, and it watches for upstream changes - exactly what you were asking for...

Comment: Ah, of course. But again, reading the script I see that urlwatch simply performs diff of upstream's webpage retrieved in different times. More robust, yes, but too "primitive" for my taste.

Comment: Fair enough. It works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the `wordpress` package's QA site](http://packages.qa.debian.org/w/wordpress.html), I suppose it gives you what `debian/watch` outputs in the "todo" box:

> - There are 6 open security issues, please fix them.
> - **A new upstream version is available: [3.5~beta2](http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.5-beta2.tar.gz), you should consider packaging it.**
> - Some strings of this package need translation. You should check the l10n status report for more information.

(I'm not sure how to automate things from here; you could subscribe to the packages QA status via email (at the bottom left of the page), I guess.  Not sure if this includes "todo".)

That said, please be aware that the [`debian/watch` script](http://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch/) *does not* depend on maintainer action, but tells you (and the maintainer) when there's a new upstream version.  (Packaging this version for Debian is a completely different issue and not what you asked for (right?).)

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. The debian/watch script will need to be updated by the maintainer if the upstream URL changes, but that happens with every watcher.

Answer (score 0):

Cobbling together your own script, you may be able to use a site like [Fossies](http://fossies.org/unix/www/) and just regex or xpath match for the lines containing the software you want to track.

Comment: That's eventually what I'll do. But I'm fishing for a prior art first here :)

Answer (score 0):

There's http://apsstandard.org/ but this is only for web apps and does not provide a way to query upstream directly. It is not unlike the Debian's (or some other distro's) repository in that regard.